# SQL Backup issues / Operating system error 995

Tags: sql-server, backup, errors

Last night backups of some databases failed. Backups are being performed using  `CommVault`. Below is error message in SQL Server logs

> 01/05/2016
>   23:03:58,spid58,Unknown,BackupVirtualDeviceFile::SendFileInfoBegin: 
>   failure on backup device '{051A54E1-01B8-4F24-BCB3-A63A7B43D100}5'.
>   Operating system error 995(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105). 01/05/2016 23:03:58,spid58,Unknown,Error: 18210
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016
>   23:03:58,spid59,Unknown,BackupVirtualDeviceFile::SendFileInfoBegin: 
>   failure on backup device '{051A54E1-01B8-4F24-BCB3-A63A7B43D100}7'.
>   Operating system error 995(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105). 01/05/2016 23:03:58,spid59,Unknown,Error: 18210
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016
>   23:03:58,spid61,Unknown,BackupVirtualDeviceFile::SendFileInfoBegin: 
>   failure on backup device '{051A54E1-01B8-4F24-BCB3-A63A7B43D100}6'.
>   Operating system error 995(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105). 01/05/2016 23:03:58,spid61,Unknown,Error: 18210
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016
>   23:03:58,spid63,Unknown,BackupVirtualDeviceFile::SendFileInfoBegin: 
>   failure on backup device '{051A54E1-01B8-4F24-BCB3-A63A7B43D100}9'.
>   Operating system error 995(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105). 01/05/2016 23:03:58,spid63,Unknown,Error: 18210
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016
>   23:03:58,spid57,Unknown,BackupVirtualDeviceFile::SendFileInfoBegin: 
>   failure on backup device '{051A54E1-01B8-4F24-BCB3-A63A7B43D100}4'.
>   Operating system error 995(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105). 01/05/2016 23:03:58,spid57,Unknown,Error: 18210
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016
>   23:03:58,spid62,Unknown,BackupVirtualDeviceFile::SendFileInfoBegin: 
>   failure on backup device '{051A54E1-01B8-4F24-BCB3-A63A7B43D100}8'.
>   Operating system error 995(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105). 01/05/2016 23:03:58,spid62,Unknown,Error: 18210
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,BACKUP failed to complete the
>   command BACKUP DATABASE master. Check the backup application log for
>   detailed messages. 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,Error: 3041
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,BACKUP failed to complete the
>   command BACKUP DATABASE SUNDOMAIN_WLD. Check the backup application
>   log for detailed messages. 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,Error:
>   3041 Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,BACKUP failed to complete the
>   command BACKUP DATABASE db1_TST. Check the backup application log for
>   detailed messages. 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,Error: 3041
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,BACKUP failed to complete the
>   command BACKUP DATABASE msdb. Check the backup application log for
>   detailed messages. 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,Error: 3041
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,BACKUP failed to complete the
>   command BACKUP DATABASE Db2_User. Check the backup application log for
>   detailed messages. 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,Error: 3041
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016
>   23:03:58,spid60,Unknown,BackupVirtualDeviceFile::SendFileInfoBegin: 
>   failure on backup device '{051A54E1-01B8-4F24-BCB3-A63A7B43D100}3'.
>   Operating system error 995(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105). 01/05/2016 23:03:58,spid60,Unknown,Error: 18210
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016
>   23:03:58,spid54,Unknown,BackupVirtualDeviceFile::SendFileInfoBegin: 
>   failure on backup device '{051A54E1-01B8-4F24-BCB3-A63A7B43D100}2'.
>   Operating system error 995(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105). 01/05/2016 23:03:58,spid54,Unknown,Error: 18210
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,BACKUP failed to complete the
>   command BACKUP DATABASE Db1_database. Check the backup application log
>   for detailed messages. 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,Error:
>   3041 Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016
>   23:03:58,spid51,Unknown,BackupVirtualDeviceFile::SendFileInfoBegin: 
>   failure on backup device '{051A54E1-01B8-4F24-BCB3-A63A7B43D100}1'.
>   Operating system error 995(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105). 01/05/2016 23:03:58,spid51,Unknown,Error: 18210
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.
>
> 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,BACKUP failed to complete the
>   command BACKUP DATABASE model. Check the backup application log for
>   detailed messages. 01/05/2016 23:03:58,Backup,Unknown,Error: 3041
>   Severity: 16 State: 1.

Comment: Is this the only message in Logs. The error 995 says that `The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an applica
tion request.` Above message is not completely helpful

Comment: I know, I don't have any other error message or info.

Comment: Sounds like the SQL server either doesn't have permissions to write to your backup device (SAN?) or it does not have access to it, or it does not exists.

Comment: What does it syas when you check the history of the job?

Comment: Add the SQL Server version as a tag please. Are you using either SQL Server 2008 or 2008 R2?  Also what are you using for backups?  Is it a VDI implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2 have this problem according to some pages.  These are areas for you to check, though I am unsure of the technology you are using.

One easy problem to look into is: [How much Disk Space Available for Backups](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6e1201e1-b622-41a1-b470-18e77d326089/error-18210-severity-16-state-1-and-backup-error-3041-severity-16-state-1)

> Includes a note saying:  *After cleaning up old backup files I re-run the backup job and it succeeded.*

Some other entries that seem to cluster around the problem can be found below.

1. [Troubleshooting VSS Writer issues](http://dbcouncil.net/2012/01/17/troubleshooting-vss-writer-issues/)
2. [How to troubleshoot "Msg 3041" in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2646329)

And an example from a specific vendor, Commvault:

3. [SQL backup failing with SQLQUERY Failure or VDITimeout](https://forum.commvault.com/forums/thread/42473.aspx)

I do not have specific experience with this, but I see a few posts that have not been answered successfully, so just pointing you to other resources.

Answer (score 0):

We had an end user that had their databases compatibility level set at SQL 2005 on a SQL 2012 instance, they never upgraded it. They were getting this same error in CommVault.

The hourly log backups were intermittently failing.

We haven't seen the error since setting the compatibility level to SQL 2012 (110).